# How to make a RegEx query only match the whole string?

Tags: regex, vba

I'm using VBA in Excel 2012 to match the contents in cells to a regular expression, but it's not working.

I'm running the following code:

```
Dim r1 As New RegExp
r1.Pattern = "(.)(\s+)?((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(\s+)(\d+)?"
r1.IgnoreCase = True

For i = 1 To 5
    If r1.Test(Sheet3.Cells.Item(i, 5)) = True Then
        MsgBox ("MATCH: " & Sheet3.Cells.Item(i, 5))
    Else
        MsgBox ("NOT MATCH: " & Sheet3.Cells.Item(i, 5))
    End If
Next i
```

So it should match the string: "A Person 01"
But not match: "A Person abc 01"

But it's matching both as the expressin can be found in the second half of the string.
How do you get it to match the whole string only?
So only match if the whole contents of the cell is: a single letter, a space, a word, a space, a number

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z]\s+\w+\s+\d+$
```

If you want to match exactly you would have to specify the start(`^`) and end(`$`)..

`[a-zA-Z]` matches a single alphabet

`\s+` matches 1 to many space

`\w+` matches a word..it is similar to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`

`\d+` matches 1 to many digits

Comment: Thanks, didnt work though. I tried ^.\s+?[a-z][a-z]+(\s)(\d+)$ which didn't work, but works in http://regexpal.com/ if you have the "^$ match at line breaks (m)" box ticked, I'm not sure what this means though or how to replicate it in my VBA code?

Comment: @user2096512 set the Multiline property to True

Comment: Ok, got it working, had some leading spaces in the cells so used the Trim() functions. Cheers.